# Bluetooth speaker not connecting on on Arch Linux / KDE Plasma

Tags: arch-linux, kde, bluetooth, plasma

I'm running Arch Linux with KDE Plasma. When I try to connect to a wireless Bluetooth speaker through the KDE Plasma GUI, it fails.

Here's the step-by-step I go thru in screenshots. I click "add device," then click the button that says the "PIN" matches. Note, since it's a Bluetooth speaker, there is no PIN. So it doesn't matter if I click "PIN matches" or the other option, the next screen says the setup has failed.

When I boot into Windows 10, it can connect to the speaker. My smart phone also connects to the speaker.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the output of `systemsettings5`. When I tried connecting to the speaker, I first clicked that the PIN matches, then I clicked the button that says it does not.

```
Fontconfig error: "/home/chris/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 10: junk after document element
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml" and "file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml"
file:///usr/share/kpackage/genericqml/org.kde.systemsettings.sidebar/contents/ui/SubCategoryPage.qml:142:9: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/share/kpackage/genericqml/org.kde.systemsettings.sidebar/contents/ui/SubCategoryPage.qml:132:9: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/RefreshableScrollView.qml:137:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/RefreshableScrollView.qml:137:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml" and "file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml"
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
file:///usr/share/kpackage/genericqml/org.kde.systemsettings.sidebar/contents/ui/introPage.qml:109:27: QML IntroIcon (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "minimumHeight"
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml" and "file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/styles/org.kde.desktop.plasma/Units.qml"
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/templates/AbstractApplicationHeader.qml:162:9: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/templates/AbstractApplicationHeader.qml:99:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/BreadcrumbControl.qml:24:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
Fontconfig error: "/home/chris/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 10: junk after document element
bluedevil.wizard: Manager initialized
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Discover Page
bluedevil.wizard: Starting scanning
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/templates/SwipeListItem.qml:190:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
bluedevil.wizard: Stopping scanning
bluedevil.wizard: PIN:  "0000"
bluedevil.wizard: Device type:  "headset"
bluedevil.wizard: Legacy:  false
bluedevil.wizard: From DB:  true
bluedevil.wizard: PIN:  "0000"
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Pairing Page
bluedevil.wizard: AGENT-RequestConfirmation  "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_FD_5C_3E_4B" "119598"
bluedevil.wizard: Pairing finished:
bluedevil.wizard:        error     :  false
bluedevil.wizard:        errorText :  ""
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Connect Page
kf.bluezqt: PendingCall Error: "Protocol not available"
bluedevil.wizard: Connect finished:
bluedevil.wizard:        error     :  true
bluedevil.wizard:        errorText :  "Protocol not available"
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Fail Page
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Discover Page
bluedevil.wizard: Starting scanning
bluedevil.wizard: Wizard done:  0
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/FormLayout.qml:337:13: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/PageRowGlobalToolBarUI.qml:65:9: QML RowLayout (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "maximumWidth"
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/PageRowGlobalToolBarUI.qml:65:9: QML RowLayout (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "maximumWidth"
Fontconfig error: "/home/chris/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line 10: junk after document element
bluedevil.wizard: Manager initialized
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Discover Page
bluedevil.wizard: Starting scanning
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/templates/SwipeListItem.qml:190:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
bluedevil.wizard: Stopping scanning
bluedevil.wizard: PIN:  "0000"
bluedevil.wizard: Device type:  "headset"
bluedevil.wizard: Legacy:  false
bluedevil.wizard: From DB:  true
bluedevil.wizard: PIN:  "0000"
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Pairing Page
bluedevil.wizard: AGENT-RequestConfirmation  "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_4E_FD_5C_3E_4B" "796571"
kf.bluezqt: PendingCall Error: "Authentication Failed"
bluedevil.wizard: Pairing finished:
bluedevil.wizard:        error     :  true
bluedevil.wizard:        errorText :  "Authentication Failed"
bluedevil.wizard: Initialize Fail Page
bluedevil.wizard: Wizard done:  0
```

Comment: Is it a dual boot computer? If you have already paired the bluetooth MAC of this machine with Windows key, the speaker might be unwilling to connect to the same MAC on Linux which is unable to provide the key it was paired on Windows with.

Comment: Are we sure it's a bluetooth issue with speaker or a more general bluetooth-issue? In a few words, are you able to connect with other than speaker/headphone bluetooth devices? i.e. bluetooth keyboard

Comment: Try to provide more logs / error messages by running `systemsettings5` in the console. Then I'd first try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_Headset#Headset_via_Bluez5/PulseAudio (if using pulseaudio which you can check in audio settings).

Comment: @Zaroth My machine failed to connect when I booted into Arch. Then when I booted into Windows, it paired. When I booted back into Arch, no luck.

Comment: @mattia.b89 Hmm, can't connect to my phone via Bluetooth either.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm Updated my answer to include output of `systemsettings5`. When I run `bluetoothctl` in console, I get the error "command not found."

Comment: The error seems to be `[...] kf.bluezqt: PendingCall Error: Authentication Failed"`. You need to have `bluez` (or `bluez-utils`) installed for bluetoothctl (I thought it was preinstalled). I'd also try a few other bluetooth managers: try installing `blueman` and connect via that. Also install `pulseaudio-bluetooth` as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Audio).

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm I installed `bluez-utils`, then followed the instructions in the Arch wiki. Bluetooth connection works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE's bluetooth manager `bluedevil` seems to have failed due to this error:

```
[...] kf.bluezqt: PendingCall Error: Authentication Failed"
```

You could try a few other GUIs listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Graphical), such as `blueman`. (You can install them with your package manager.) Don't install `gnome-control-center` if you're not using GNOME though.

If they don't work either try this:

- In the konsole run

  ```
  sudo pacman -S pulseaudio-alsa pulseaudio-bluetooth bluez-utils bluez
  ```
- Then run `bluetoothctl` and follow [these instructions from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_Headset#Configuration_via_CLI) (you probably don't need the part under "Media controls").
- If it still doesn't work run `systemsettings5` in the console and ask about it with the logs.

Comment: One issue, Arch uses ‘pacman’, not apt-get.